# add to cart button doesnt works in ionic app

Tags: android, html, ionic-framework

i have icymobi source code from codecanyon. i want add to cart button in wishlist page but when i added it, button doesn't adds product to cart.

[image]

this is wishlist.html

```
<ion-view title="{{$root.appLanguage.WISHLISH_TEXT}} "  class="product-detail" hide-tabs>
<ion-content class="has-footer">
    <div class="product-list clearfix wish">
        <div class="product-item" ng-repeat="product in products" >
            <div class="img product-img"  ng-click="openProduct({{product[2].id}})">
                <img actual-src="{{product[2].images[0].src}}" ng-src="img/placeholder.png">
            </div>
            <div class="meta text-left">
                <div class="on-sale" ng-if="product.on_sale">{{$root.appLanguage.PRODUCT_SALE_TEXT}}</div>
                    <div class="title-item">
                        <h2 class="name name-pro" ng-bind-html="product[2].name" ng-click="openProduct({{product[2].id}})"></h2>
                        <p class="name name-cat" ng-bind-html="product[2].name" ng-click="openProduct({{product[2].id}})"></p>
                        <div class="price price-whislist" ng-if="product[2].price_html" ng-bind-html="product[2].price_html"></div>
                        <div class="text-center">
<div ng-if="!isInWishlist" class="wishlist-button" ng-click="addProductToWishlist()" style="font-size: 20px; color:#FF0000;">
                    <i class="ion-heart"></i>
                </div>
                </div>
                <button  id="addtobag" class="bar-footer button button-positive" ng-click="addProductToCart()" add-to-cart-button>{{$root.appLanguage.ADD_TO_CART_TEXT}}</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you right click, inspect element, view the console tab and monitor the error(s) that appear in there, that will give you more of an idea of what the blocker is at this point for the click. Also, this is an older Angular / Ionic setup, the new click method takes place using `(click)="method()"`

Comment: can you help using teamviewer? im seriously trying from 2 days with no sucess